# Client is not sending ACK in response to server's FIN ACK in Python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I am using the socket library in python and to connect to a server. After connecting, the server will automatically transmit packets and then terminate the connection. I am having issues completing the proper hand shaking to close the connection.

After receiving the server's packets, I set an indefinite while loop to wait for the server to initiate the close:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((ip_address, port))

...
# Get packets
...

# Wait for server to close connection
while True:
    new_msg = s.recv(1024)
    if len(new_msg) <= 0:
        break
```

With this code, I see the following network traffic for the closing process:

```
Server -> Client: FIN, ACK
Client -> Server: FIN, ACK
Server -> Client: ACK
```

I would like to see:

```
Server -> Client: FIN, ACK
Client -> Server: ACK
Client -> Server: FIN, ACK
Server -> Client: ACK
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You don't need the ACK for anything here, and the client not *sending* it cannot possibly cause the client's own final *read* loop to block forever. Receiving the FIN will cause `len(new_msg) <= 0` to become true. I don't see any point in this final read loop. Your *prior* reads must have already terminated on this condition, otherwise you would still be executing them.  Just close the socket and forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably caused by `Delayed ACK`. The app terminates earlier than expected and the ACK is never sent.

[From the RFC 1122, section 4.2.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-96) - *When to Send an ACK Segment*, *A host that is receiving a stream of TCP data segments can increase efficiency in both the Internet and the hosts by sending fewer than one ACK (acknowledgement) segment per data segment received; this is known as a "delayed ACK"*.

You can try disabling the `Delayed ACK` and check if this happens again. It depends on the platform you're using (Linux or Windows).

Comment: You should be able to disable delayed ack on Linux using `s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_QUICKACK, 0)`. I don't know of a way to disable it on Windows.

Comment: But none of this will address the alleged problem, which has nothing to do with the final ACK.